# link gcc object and pgfortran object together( both have omp directives inside)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, g++, fortran90

Now I'm working with a scientific project in which we use fortran-cuda from PGI. We have found that PGI's omp support is so poor that we can not have paralleled omp task by pgfortran. So we decided to pull out something out and make it C++ and compile it with g++.

The other reason why we want to mix PGI's pgfortran compiler with GNU's g++ is that we need to use the pgfortran to compile the cuda-fortran part of our code and we also need to use NVCC from Nvidia( which use g++ to compile the host code) to compile that OMP segments which have CUDA in them and which can not be compiled correctly by pgfortran.

At last when I link the C++ object files compiled by g++ and the Fortran object files compiled by pgfortran together, if I don't put a -lgomp option there, there will be link errors. But if I put it there, the behavior of OMP threads is weird.

I think the problem is that the two different compiler use different OMP library and gomp is GNU's library. So anyone knows how to link them correctly? Or can someone tell me how to link the PGI's OMP library?

Comment: This is probably impossible.